# Disable onsave formating for .ejs files in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm working with ejs files, but in order to reuse some code, I'm using the includes feature. Given that some opening/closing html tags are placed in other files, after I save my changes, something (I don't know if prettier extension or VS code editor) is including the closing tags into my code, causing several problems when I running it.

Comment: I’m facing the same issue which makes me crazy which obliges me to use another editor for removing these close tags as a work around.

Comment: I solved my problem with the solution I marked as the best. I think that change the editor just because of this problem is a little extreme. I suggest you to try the provided solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use EJS myself, but after playing around with it in VSCode, I noticed that my `.ejs` files were being treated as HTML files. You can see how your VSCode is interpreting the file by looking in the bottom right corner of the editor. You could search for EJS extensions as well.

You likely have the "Editor: format on save" option enabled. To disable that setting, go to Preferences, and in the search bar type "format on save". Find the setting. Uncheck the box. That should fix the problem.

If, as you mentioned, your closing HTML tags are in other files, then you have invalid HTML and the formatter (both Prettier's and the default one) will autocomplete the closing tag. (I would wager EJS also wouldn't like the lack of closing tags, but since I don't use it I'm not so sure, maybe it's fine.)

Comment: By the moment I have disabled format on save from settings, nevertheless, I was looking for a way to disable this characteristic for *.ejs files. The problem is that ejs files are being treated as html code and I don't want to get out of html formating, just from the ejs files being formated as html.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want `*.ejs` files to be associated with HTML. You can do that by associating them with another file type, including even `plaintext`, which would effectively disable syntax highlighting as well as formatting. To change that setting, do the following: Open a `*.ejs` file. Click the `HTML` text in the bottom right (which represents what VSCode has autodetected the code to be). You will be presented with a dropdown, chose "Configure File Association for '.ejs'...". Within that option is another dropdown, chose "plaintext", or any other language option you want.

Comment: Thanks, I associate the file extension with plaintext and that solved my problem!

Comment: Could you elaborate how you did that?

Answer (score 4):

An other solution is to use a `.prettierignore` file and put in :

```
*.ejs
```

Comment: but you will lose formatting on save

Answer (score 3):

[image]

in your `settings.json` you should add these settings.
just instead of `"[css]"` type what you want. (the format of the file)

and just please ignore line 2 :) that's not related to this answer.

### Edit

as @aegatlin said use this: `"[html]"`.(if `"[ejs]"` didn't work for you)

Comment: is there a way to specify just the type of file extension that I want to disable? cause, given that ejs is not a programming language then, I can't disabling it without disabling html...

Comment: See this, it may help. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35350

Comment: And .... also this one. https://medium.com/@zulhhandyplast/how-to-disable-vs-code-formatonsave-for-specific-file-extensions-c60e8f254243

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with my "header.ejs", it was auto closing the body, main and html tags, which needed to be open for the index.ejs.

A quick fix is to just disable Prettier in the extensions tab on the left before saving that particular file.

As the file doesn't have many changes, when I add to it I just disable Prettier, save the file then reenable Prettier.

For you, if that's the only issue you are getting with Prettier you could save changing that line of code until you have finished working on the file then disable, save, enable.

Answer (score 0):

Zulhilmi Zainudin has the solution
https://medium.com/@zulhhandyplast/how-to-disable-vs-code-formatonsave-for-specific-file-extensions-c60e8f254243

In vscode setting file, associate ejs extentions files to a « language ». Then you can specify different rules for this that language :

**.vscode/settings.json** file content :

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.ejs": "ejs" // this create the language « ejs » which refers to any .ejs file
    },
    "[ejs]": { // custom settings for the language « ejs »
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but then all of the HTML syntax highlighting I typically enjoy disappeared.

I reverted everything and just added my one problem file to .prettierignore. This isn't perfect but I get to keep my syntax highlighting and other developers who checkout the project from git won't ever run into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add .prettierignore file to your project folder
2. add the file names you want prettier to ignore inside the .prettierignore file